# How is age(datfrozenxid) calculated in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

The postgres documentation says:

> "The age column measures the number of transactions from the cutoff
>   XID to the current transaction's XID."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XIDs are just sequential numbers, so calculating the "age" of an XID is simple subtraction, i.e.:

```
age(datfrozenxid) = txid_current() - datfrozenxid
```

XIDs for data created during `initdb`, as well as for data frozen prior to Postgres 9.4, will always report an age of 2147483647.

The full source code of the `age()` function (all five lines of it) can be found [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_2/src/backend/utils/adt/xid.c#L99).

Comment: Thanks Nick, what is datfrozenxid ?

Comment: It's explained in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) you mentioned: `it is just the minimum of the per-table relfrozenxid values within the database`

Comment: From your answer and checking the source code, in case of a txid wraparound, we can have, for instance, txid_current() = 1000 and datfrozenxid = 4.294.967.000 (a value very near the wraparound). I believe Age would have a weird behavior, returning the negative number -4.294.966.000‬, because it does't handle wraparounds. I did not confirm this in a real test yet due to be a little difficult to prepare a real wraparound test, but from source, it is expected. This has prevented us from using age for certain use cases so far. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Thiago: Sure looks that way to me... It'll take ~12 hours to test, but I'll try and get around to it some time.